# Securing Digital Heritage

Tags: wallet-security, smartcontracts, inheritance-plan, custody

I would like to bequeath my digital assets in a secure way. I am the sole custodian of my bitcoins. I would like to release or pass custody conditionally, like upon death. This has to happen in a secure way.

Obviously, I can pass down my wallets' seed phrases. The unclear part is how to do it conditionally, for instance upon death, at the same time as doing it securely.

**Initial thoughts:**

1. Put the information in a cloud password manager that allows for a digital heir. One example is the Emergency Contact functionality of Last Pass.
2. Store the information in a deposit box, in a bank.

Both of these seem to achieve the goals. Any inheritance will be passed down upon death. Also the information is kept with some security.

The Last Pass Scenario is shakier. Possibly, the Emergency contact already needs to have your master password. It's easier for Last Pass to get hacked than for bank deposit box to be broken into. Possibly, LastPass will not exist when I am dead.

Both of these options are not without cost.

**Question:**

What other options exist for passing down information securely and conditionally, for instance upon death? Has anyone deployed a smart contract to this end? How would this work?

Comment: No worries, your question is on-topic here. Please also check out other questions on the tag [tag:bequesting-bitcoin]. I think these might be related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/38692/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/44426/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/61705/5406. OTOH, I think there has been significant innovation related to your question, so a refresher is definitely in order.